# How to find closest 2d point/points efficiently

Tags: python, search

I am trying to find out the shortest path on a map using modified A* algorithm considering my robot dynamics.
My search space is 2d and so is the planned path
But my map is dynamic and at the start of each loop the map changes a little.

If i try to find a path in every loop,the fps drops below zero as my search space is very big.
What i want to do is, to check if the path plotted in the previous path is still valid or not as most of the times it is.

For this i did the following - 
Here The array obstacles and array contain a bunch of 2d points(upto 2000000)

```
def check_collision(path,obstacles):
max_distance = 5
collision = False
for i in len(path):
    for j in len(obstacles):
        distance = math.sqrt((path[i][0] - obstacles[j][0])**2 + (path[i][1] - obstacles[j][1])**2)
        if distance< max_distance:
            collision = True
            break

    return collison
```

I think this is slowing my  loops badly

Is there any faster way to do this?